# MongoDB Aggregate Group Results Query by Common Fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

Looking to figure out how to perform a particular grouping of Mongo documents through a query, instead of transforming the results through code after getting the data.

Sample mock data:

```
[
    { 'id': 1, 'status': 'EMPTY', 'name': 'ALBERT' },
    { 'id': 2, 'status': 'EMPTY', 'name': 'ERIC' },
    { 'id': 3, 'status': 'EMPTY', 'name': 'ALBERT' },
    { 'id': 4, 'status': 'EMPTY', 'name': 'ALBERT' },
    { 'id': 5, 'status': 'EMPTY', 'name': 'JESSICA' },
    { 'id': 6, 'status': 'EMPTY', 'name': 'ERIC' },
    ...
]
```

My aggregate query:

```
db.results.aggregate([
    { 
        $match: {
            'status': 'EMPTY'
        }
    },
    ???
])
```

I would like to transform/sort the results into an object like this:

```
{
    'ALBERT': [
        { 'id': 1, 'status': 'EMPTY', 'name': 'ALBERT' },
        { 'id': 3, 'status': 'EMPTY', 'name': 'ALBERT' },
        { 'id': 4, 'status': 'EMPTY', 'name': 'ALBERT' },
    ],
    'ERIC': [
        { 'id': 2, 'status': 'EMPTY', 'name': 'ERIC' },
        { 'id': 6, 'status': 'EMPTY', 'name': 'ERIC' }
    ],
    'JESSICA': [
        { 'id': 5, 'status': 'EMPTY', 'name': 'JESSICA' }
    ]
}
```

It's a bit difficult looking through documentation online since I'm not even sure what this type of transformation is called, or what aggregator I should be using in Mongo. So any point in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unset: "_id" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      data: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        k: "$_id",
        v: "$data"
      }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$data" } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: "$data" } } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XCjoqu9_Uyt)

Comment: Thank you!! This didn't work right out the box due to mongo version differences I believe, but definitely seems like a step in the right direction!

Comment: The `$replaceWith` is an alias for `$replaceRoot` and introduced in MongoDB 4.2. Use `{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$data" } } }` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Ended up figuring that out as well, since we're on mongo 3.6. It works well not using the alias other than the results being an array of objects `[ { "ERIC": [...] }, { "ALBERT": [...] }, { "JESSICA": [...] } ]`. I think I was looking more for something like: `[ {"ERIC": [...], "ALBERT": [...], "JESSICA": [...] } ]` (array with one element with results). Not sure if this can be done in Mongo queries though

Comment: Please see my update, added two more stages.

Comment: This is now working splendidly with my data! Thank you very much! Definitely learned a lot playing around and analyzing how all the stages work. Much appreciated! :]